# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Unable to change the default WL.BusyIndicator text

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I've test WL.BusyIndicator like following code:

```
    busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', {
    text : 'saving'
});
busyIndicator.show();
setTimeout(function() {
    busyIndicator.hide();
}, 3000);
```

The Information Center says [BusyIndicator options can get 'text' in Android environment](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_busyindicator.html).

I can see the BusyIndicator shown on my Android Emulator (v4.0.4/v4.1.2/v4.2.2) but the text is default 'Loading'...

Note: the same happens in iOS as well.

My Worklight Studio version is: 6.0.0.201307241843

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
function wlCommonInit(){

    WL.ClientMessages.loading = "Hello world :)";

    var busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content'); 
    busyInd.show();

    setTimeout(function () {
        busyInd.hide();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Notice that I'm using `WL.ClientMessages.loading` to set the message, instead of passing an object with the `text` key to the constructor.

I had to look at the Busy Indicator code to figure out what was wrong, I'll open a defect. Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: great this is working for me..But any idea  why text key to the constructor is not working???

Comment: The key/value pair passed is being overwritten by WL.ClientMessages.loading before the Cordova plugin that shows the busy indicator is called.

Comment: Ok Thanks cnandreu. So what if, I want to use different busy indicator at different part of project.Do i need to overwrite text every time ??? or there a way to create multiple  busy indicator object with different text???

Comment: Wait for some to fix the defect or overwrite the text every time. Palease open new StackOverflow questions for further inquiries.